# Run cmake Qt creator error

Tags: cmake, ros

I am trying to open a ros package in Qt creator but isn't working. Every time I run cmake the following errors occur:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (catkin_package):   Unknown CMake
>   command "catkin_package".
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):   Could not find
>   module Findcatkin.cmake or a configuration file for package   catkin.
>
> Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcatkin.cmake or set catkin_DIR
>   to the   directory containing a CMake configuration file for catkin. 
>   The file will   have one of the following names:

```
catkinConfig.cmake
catkin-config.cmake
```

I don't know what to do, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

As stated on the [ROS wiki page about IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator), to open a ROS node in QtCreator you have to...

1. Make sure, that the setup.bash of your catkin workspace is sourced. You can add `source ~/path/to/your/ws/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc`, then you don't have to do it manually for every terminal. (This point is not mentioned on the liked wiki page).
2. Run QtCreator in a terminal (or use the desktop file from the linked wiki page).
3. Open the CMakeLists.txt of the whole workspace, not the one of a single package (otherwise compiling within QtCreator will not work properly)
   **Note:** The CMakeLists.txt of the workspace is only a link to a file somewhere in /opt/ros. This will cause problems for QtCreator, therefore remove the link and copy the file instead (The exact location of the file that has to be copied can be displayed with `ls -l CMakeLists.txt`).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help... I followed your instructions and found the location:                                                                                                                                                                                                            /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake                                                                                                                                                                                                            But where should I paste it? Build location?

Comment: How do I instruct QtCreator to open the main CMakeLists.txt file of the whole catkin workspace?

Comment: Assuming your catkin workspace is located in `~/catkin_ws`. Replace `~/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt` with the `toplevel.cmake` (of course make sure that the file still is named `CMakeLists.txt`). Then open this file in QtCreator (using the normal "open file or project" dialog). QtCreator will then ask you, where to locate the build directory. This has to be set to `~/catkin_ws/build`.

Comment: Ah, now I understood. It worked, thanks very much, I appreciate your help. I can go ahead with my project now :D

Comment: Point 2 did it for me! Thanks !